# Ubuntu 16.04: WiFi BCM43142 doesn't see nearby networks

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 16.04, broadcom

I've just bought an Acer ES1-521 laptop. First thing I did was to boot into the BIOS setup, change boot order to USB DVD-Drive first and install Ubuntu 16.04 from a DVD (everybody does that, right?).

However, it doesn't recognize the nearby networks, in particular the one I configured in my wireless router. I tried quite a few things to make it work. First I ran:

```
wlpci -nn | grep Network
```

to see my wireless device. Result is:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
```

Looking on the Internet, I figured out I needed to install driver bcmwl-kernel-source. Here's what 'rfkill list all' returned before I did this:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: acer-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

Then I ran:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

and as gentleman chili555 pointed-out, I added the following lines into file etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf:

```
blacklist b43
blacklist bcma
blacklist ssb
```

Then I re-booted but the problem is not resolved. Here's what 'rfkill list all' gives me now:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
3: acer-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

Seems my wireless is still hard blocked; here's what 'nmcli g' returns:

```
STATE      CONNECTIVITY  WIFI-HW  WIFI      WWAN-HW  WWAN     
connected  full          enabled  disabled  enabled  disabled
```

I ran 'nmcli radio wifi on' but 'nmcli g' gives the same result, so I can't turn on the WiFi. Needless to say, my wireless adapter doesn't support scanning. I looked at the doc of bcmwl-kernel-source and it says it supports BCM43xxx up to BCM4313x but not the BCM42142 that I have.

Could someone help me?

Thanks,

Desperate Andre

Answer (score 2):

Run in terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist_acer-wmi.conf <<< "blacklist acer_wmi"
```

and reboot.

It does not matter where to add the blacklist line to `blacklist.conf` or a separate file. But it is a good practice to add custom modprobe config to separate files, not to be overwritten by package updates.

Comment: It works now,  thanks a lot Pilot6! Could you be kind enough to tell me: (1) why did I need to create file blacklist_acer-wmi.conf, and (2) why not adding the line 'blacklist acer_wmi' to file blacklist.conf? Thanks again.

Comment: I explained it in the answer.